# Как считать из QTextEdit float значение?

Tags: python, pyqt, float, qtextedit, qdoublespinbox

Есть поле `textEdit_LOT_SD`, в которое вводиться `float` значение (одно) и при нажатии кнопки эта переменная передается в функцию в другой файл для последующей работы.

Как считать значение в виде `float`? Или перевести его в `float`?

Вот что имеется сейчас:

```
self.textEdit_LOT_SD=QTextEdit(self)
LOT_SD_r=self.textEdit_LOT_SD.toPlainText()
```

попытка добавить `LOT_SD_m=float(LOT_SD_r)` приводить к ошибке:

> could not convert string to float

Comment: Вы вводите значение с десятичной запятой вместо десятичной точки?

Comment: Так и делать. Видимо строка у Вас кривая какая-то, нужен пример строки.

Comment: данные вводятся с использованием точки, не запятой

Comment: вот пример где используется переменная  `SErm=LOT_SD_m/5.16`

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, предоставьте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Странно использовать виджет `QTextEdit` для этих целей.

Класс [**QDoubleSpinBox**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdoublespinbox.html#details) предоставляет виджет счетчика, который принимает двойные значения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *                


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()   
        
        self.textEdit_LOT_SD = QTextEdit(self)
        
        self.spinBox = QDoubleSpinBox(self)                                 # !!! 
        
        self.label = QLabel()

        self.button = QPushButton('Click me')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEdit_LOT_SD)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        
        self.textEdit_LOT_SD.setFocus()
            
    def button_clicked(self):
        if not self.textEdit_LOT_SD.toPlainText() or not self.spinBox.value():
            self.textEdit_LOT_SD.setFocus()
            return
        try:
            LOT_SD_r = float(self.textEdit_LOT_SD.toPlainText())
    # -----------> ^ <--> v <-------------------------------------------------- !!!
            SErm = LOT_SD_r / self.spinBox.value()
            
            text = f'{LOT_SD_r} / {self.spinBox.value()} = {SErm:.3f}'
            self.label.setText(text)
        except:
            self.textEdit_LOT_SD.setFocus()
            return
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @gigi что не так?